# Error al iniciar proyecto nuevo de Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, npm

Tengo un problema cada vez que quiero iniciar un nuevo proyecto en angular con el comando  no se a que se deba y ya actualice npm, node, angular y typescript a la ultima version para ver si asi resolvia el error pero nada. 
¿Alguna forma en que lo pueda resolver? Adjunto la imagen para que lo vean.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener instalado nodeJS,también typescript, luego instalar angular cli, te dejo el link de angular CLI para que veas como se instala correctamente

angular cli:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki

verifica que tengas instalado nodeJS con el comando 'node -v' y para corroborar que se instaló correctamente el paquete npm solo ejecuta 'npm -v'

Comment: Ya lo hice, desinstale todo lo que tenia y lo volvi a instalar pero nada.